# Filtering and parsing text over Solar Region Summary files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to filter some .txt files that are named after a date in YYYYMMDD format and contain some data about active regions in the Sun. I made a code that, given a date in YYYYMMDD format, can list the files that are within a time range which I expect the active region I am looking for to be and parse the information based on that entry. An example of these txts can be seen below and more information about it (if you feel curious) can be seen on [SWPC website](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/solar-region-summary).

```
:Product: 0509SRS.txt
:Issued: 2012 May 09 0030 UTC
# Prepared jointly by the U.S. Dept. of Commerce, NOAA,
# Space Weather Prediction Center and the U.S. Air Force.
#
Joint USAF/NOAA Solar Region Summary
SRS Number 130 Issued at 0030Z on 09 May 2012
Report compiled from data received at SWO on 08 May
I.  Regions with Sunspots.  Locations Valid at 08/2400Z 
Nmbr Location  Lo  Area  Z   LL   NN Mag Type
1470 S19W68   284  0030 Cro  02   02 Beta
1471 S22W60   277  0120 Cso  05   03 Beta
1474 N14W13   229  0010 Axx  00   01 Alpha
1476 N11E35   181  0940 Fkc  17   33 Beta-Gamma-Delta
1477 S22E73   144  0060 Hsx  03   01 Alpha
IA. H-alpha Plages without Spots.  Locations Valid at 08/2400Z May
Nmbr  Location  Lo
1472  S28W80   297
1475  N05W05   222
II. Regions Due to Return 09 May to 11 May
Nmbr Lat    Lo
1460 N16    126
1459 S16    110
```

The code I am using to parse over these txt files is:

```
import glob

def seeker(noaa_number, t_start, path = None):
    '''
    This function will open an SRS file
    and look for each line if the given AR
    (specified by its NOAA number) is there.
    If so, this function should grab the
    entries and return them.
    '''

    #defaulting path if none is given
    if path is None:
        #assigning
        path = 'defaultpath'


    #listing the items within the directory
    files = sorted(glob.glob(path+'*.txt'))

    #finding the index in the list of
    #the starting time
    index = files.index(path+str(t_start)+'SRS.txt')

    #looping over each file
    for file in files[index: index+20]:

        #opening file
        f = open(file, 'r')

        #reading the lines
        text = f.readlines()

        #looping over each line in the text
        for line in text:

            #checking if the noaa number is mentioned
            #in the given line
            if noaa_number in line:

                #test print
                print('Original line: ', line)

                #slicing the text to get the column values
                nbr = line[:4]
                Location = line[5:11]
                Lo = line[14:18]
                Area = line[19:23]
                Z = line[24:28]
                LL = line[29:31]
                NN = line[34:36]
                MagType = line[37:]

                #test prints
                print('nbr: ', nbr)
                print('location: ', Location)
                print('Lo: ', Lo)
                print('Area: ', Area)
                print('Z: ', Z)
                print('LL: ', LL)
                print('NN: ', NN)
                print('MagType: ', MagType)

     return
```

I tested this and it is working but I fell a bit dumb for two reasons:

- Despite these files being made following a standard, one extra space is all it takes to crash the code considering the way I am slicing the arrays by index. Is there a better option to that?
- The information on tables IA and II are not relevant for me so, ideally, I would like to prevent my code to scan them. Since the number of lines on the first column varies, is it possible to tell the code when to stop reading a giving document?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you heard about ["Regular Expressions"](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html)? It is a programming method for searching patterns in a string. Mapped to your case, you can see the table as lines following all the same pattern, where there are portions of substrings separeted by some white spaces.

Comment: I never heard of it before. I will surely have a check. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Robustness:

Instead of slicing by absolute position you could split the lines up into a list using the `.split()` method. This will be robust against extra spaces.

So instead of

```
Location = line[5:11]
Lo = line[14:18]
Area = line[19:23]
Z = line[24:28]
LL = line[29:31]
NN = line[34:36]
```

You could use

```
Location = line.split()[1]
Lo = line.split()[2]
Area = line.split()[3]
Z = line.split()[4]
LL = line.split()[5]
NN = line.split()[6]
```

If you wanted it to be faster you could split the list once and then just pull the relevant data from the same list rather than splitting it every time:

```
data = line.split()
Location = data[1]
Lo = data[2]
Area = data[3]
Z = data[4]
LL = data[5]
NN = data[6]
```

## Stopping:

To stop it from continuing reading the file after it's passed the relevant data you could just have something that exits the loop once it no longer finds the noaa_number in the line

```
# In the file function but before looping through the lines. 

started_reading = False ## Set this to false so 
                        ## that it doesn't exit
                        ## before it gets to the 
                        ## relevant data

for line in text:
    if noaa_number in line:
        started_reading = True 

        ## Parsing stuff

    elif started_reading is True:
        break # exits the loop
```